# Tablesorter, filters not working with Ajax table load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I've tried refreshing/updating with triggers after load (doesn't work), also moving the tablesorter files to loaded url from the main page (doesn't work) . The main thing is that all the other widgets work (scroller, pagination) and the search boxes for the filter do appear - but the filtering doesn't happen.

Table:

```
<table id="teams_table" class="scroll-table" style="font-size:16px; height:280px">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Votes</th>
                <th>Odds</th>
                <th>Team </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>200</td>
                <td>1.25</td>
                <td> Seahawks </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>1.15</td>
                <td> Broncos </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>75</td>
                <td>1.10</td>
                <td>Patriots </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>1.65</td>
                <td> Raiders</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>1.65</td>
                <td> Packers </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Script:

```
    $('.scroll-table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        headerTemplate: '{content}',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'scroller', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            scroller_height: 290,
            filter_columnFilters : true,
            filter_liveSearch : true,
            filter_searchDelay : 100,
        }
    });
```

Loading from the main page like so.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#view_teams' ).click( function() {
        $( '#main' ).html( '&nbsp;' ).load( '{% url "teams_table" %}' );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

tablesorter needs to be initialized after the table has been loaded into the DOM. In this case, I would initialize it within the [`load()` callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function):

```
$( function() {
    $( '#view_teams' ).click( function() {
        $( '#main' )
            // use empty() instead of replacing contents with a space
            // this really isn't even necessary
            .empty()
            .load( '{% url "teams_table" %}', function(){
                // load callback function
                $('.scroll-table').tablesorter({
                    theme: 'blue',
                    headerTemplate: '{content}',
                    widgets: ['zebra', 'scroller', 'filter'],
                    widgetOptions: {
                        scroller_height: 290,
                        filter_columnFilters : true,
                        filter_liveSearch : true,
                        filter_searchDelay : 100,
                    }
                });
            }); // end load
    }); // end click
});
```

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to address this? The load method above is loading two tables and and some other blocks which I would hope to keep in their own respective templates.

Comment: If you replace the entire table, then I don't think there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I'm not replacing a table, there is no table to begin with - so both the table and the initializing script are being loaded together. So having several initializing table scripts on a page for tables that are only included by block components of another template, that is not necessarily even going to be rendered - is a pretty horrendous design.

Comment: Edit: also initializing in the callback did not fix anything.

Comment: So apparently the scroller widget is to blame. Actually the search on this page is not working either: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-scroller.html